# How to check whether a string value is present in a DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, exists

Im working on a code that has a TextBox, A Button and a Datagrid view.
I want to Display "Data Not Exist" when a value in TextBox is not present on the DataGridView when i press the button.

This is my code so far

```
If DataGridView1.Rows.Contains(TextBox1.Text) = False Then
         MessageBox.Show("Data Not Exist!")
End If
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. What have you tried so far? Kindly include it in your question. I'm sorry to say that this is not a _code factory_.

Comment: sorry, newbie here. i included my code

Comment: You need to search in every column and every row? or for a specific column only?

Comment: I need to search in every column and every row :)

Comment: Have you tried using a `For Loop`?

Comment: For Each row As Integer In DataGridView1.Rows
                If DataGridView1.Rows(row).Cells(0).Value = "TextBox1.text" Then
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Exists!")
                End If

            Next

I TRIED this , no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to loop through all rows and columns

```
Dim isFound As Boolean = False  

      For Each row As GridViewRow  In DataGridView1.Rows
           for i As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Columns.Count -1
         If row.Cells[i].Text = TextBox1.text  Then
            isFound = True
            exit for
         End If
           Next
        Next


 If (isFound) Then
      MessageBox.Show("Data Exists!")
 Else
       MessageBox.Show("Data Not Exists!")
 EndIf
```

Comment: `For i As Integer = 0 to DataGridView1.Columns.Count` will cause you an error since the index starts with `zero`. :)

Comment: MAN YOURE A GENIOUS! :D Thank you so much - ill post another question...

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily with either using a `LINQ` or a `ForLoop`

This code will search **all** matches it will find across the `DataGridView` and will prompt in which `Row` and `Column` it sees the match.

With a `ForLoop`, you need to run a loop for `Column` and for the `Row`.

```
Private Sub SearchUsingForLoop()
    Dim resultString As String = Nothing
    For x = 0 To DataGridView1.ColumnCount - 1
        For y = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            If DataGridView1.Item(x, y).Value.ToString.ToUpper = txtSearch.Text.ToUpper Then
                resultString &= " - Column " & x + 1 & " Row " & y + 1 & vbCrLf
            End If
        Next
    Next
    If resultString <> Nothing Then
        resultString = txtSearch.Text & " found in : " & vbCrLf & resultString
    Else
        resultString = "Data does not exist."
    End If
    MsgBox(resultString)
End Sub
```

Do remember that index of `DatagridViewRow` and `DatagridViewColumn` starts with `0`.

Another way of doing this is by `LINQ`:

```
 Private Sub SearchUsingLINQ()
    Dim resultSet = From dgRow As DataGridViewRow In Me.DataGridView1.Rows, _
           dgCell As DataGridViewCell In dgRow.Cells _
      Where dgCell.Value.ToString.ToUpper = txtSearch.Text.ToUpper _
      Select dgCell

    Dim resultString As String = Nothing
    If resultSet.Count > 0 Then
        resultString = txtSearch.Text & " found in :" & vbCrLf
        For Each dgCells In resultSet
            resultString &= " - Column " & dgCells.ColumnIndex + 1 & " Row " & dgCells.RowIndex + 1 & vbCrLf
        Next
    End If

    If resultString <> Nothing Then
        MsgBox(resultString)
    Else
        MsgBox("Data does not exist.")
    End If
End Sub
```

Feel free to use any of those. But I suggest you to study `iterating` a `DataGridView` first.